# Need help to show() hide() bottom Sequence Navigation depending on select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am displaying different sequence navigation depending on a select input. 
this is example of what I am trying to do so far:

```
                               <ul class="steps" id="dbleOpt">
<li class="active">Create<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                                <li>Fields<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                            </ul>
                        <ul class="steps" id="singleOpt">
  <li class="active">Create<span class="chevron"></span></li>
 <li>Welcome<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                            <li>Overview<span class="chevron"></span></li>
                        </ul>
```

and this is my javascript which is not working:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#singleOpt').hide();
        $('#dbleOpt').show();

        $('#Lists_opt_in').on("change",function () {
            $('#dbleOpt').hide();
            $('#singleOpt'+$(this).val()).show();
        })
    });
```

here is select input....

```
<select id="Lists_opt_in" name="Lists[opt_in]" class="form-control has-help-text">
<option value="double" selected>Double opt-in</option>
<option value="single">Single opt-in</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where is the input? what you need? give more info so we can help

Comment: some code's are missing your snippet .

Comment: Can you post an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Im going to be that guy and recommend a library. I like using KnockoutJs for things like this. You add a visible binding and call it a day. You can even use a CDN. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Comment: Okay I updated with the html and input.....doubt that helps though. The problem is hiding/showing a ul with javascript/jQuery

Comment: I wouldnt want to bring in a whole library just for this...I am sure there has to be a way with javascript and jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use some `data` attribute in option tag like this below snippet
2. Then find the `data` attribute of respected `id` to show

```js
$(function() {
  $('#singleOpt').hide();
  $('#dbleOpt').show();

  $('#Lists_opt_in').on("change", function() {
    $('.steps').hide();
    $('#'+$('option:selected', this).data('target')).show()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="steps" id="dbleOpt">
  <li class="active">Create<span class="chevron"></span></li>
  <li>Fields<span class="chevron"></span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="steps" id="singleOpt">
  <li class="active">Create<span class="chevron"></span></li>
  <li>Welcome<span class="chevron"></span></li>
  <li>Overview<span class="chevron"></span></li>
</ul>

<select id="Lists_opt_in" name="Lists[opt_in]" class="form-control has-help-text">
<option value="double"  data-target="dbleOpt"  selected>Double opt-in</option>
<option value="single" data-target="singleOpt" >Single opt-in</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, just try a single list and then use jQuery's `toggle()` method to toggle visibility:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#Lists_opt_in').on("change",function () {
     $('.dbleOpt').toggle();
     $('.singleOpt').toggle();
 })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <ul class="steps" id="dbleOpt">
      <li class="active">Create<span class="chevron"></span></li>
      <li class="dbleOpt">Fields<span class="chevron"></span></li>
      <li class="singleOpt hidden">Welcome<span class="chevron"></span></li>
      <li class="singleOpt hidden">Overview<span class="chevron"></span></li>
    </ul>
    <select id="Lists_opt_in" name="Lists[opt_in]" class="form-control has-help-text">
      <option value="double" selected>Double opt-in</option>
      <option value="single">Single opt-in</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution